# no match when using a subselect and comparing two varchar columns

Tags: sql

I'm experiencing something strange, and I can't understand why this is not working; even though it should be quite simple.

Let's say I have a query that selects into a temp table like this:

```
SELECT customer_no
INTO #temp 
FROM #old_temp
```

One temp that selects from another temp and it works. Customer_no is varchar(6). I have only one value for testing purposes: '123456'

Then the code is trying to do this:

```
SELECT customer_no
FROM #temp
WHERE customer_no NOT IN
 (SELECT cust_number from AnotherCustomerTable)
```

In AnotherCustomerTable, '123456' doesn't exist fore sure. And the customer_no is also varchar(6). What ever I try, I result is empty, while I should get '123456' in result set.

Anyone who have experienced this, and know what it could be? I tried trim functions but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Stupid me didn't consider the NULLs in the sub select. Added this:

```
SELECT cust_number from AnotherCustomerTable
WHERE cust_number IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: For those who wonders: As long as the result set in the sub select contains NULLs the query will not return any rows at all.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with your query.  Assuming customer_no '123456' exists in #old_temp, it would then be inserted in #temp.  And assuming cust_number '123456' does NOT exist in AnotherCustomerTable, then it should return the result.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da78c/1) demonstrating.  My guess is your data is incorrect.

Good luck.